# Converting a string of xml to actual xml and extracting a particular attribute

Tags: javascript, xml

I have an xml in a string. i want to extract a a particular attribute from the string. is there a way to extract.

`<mxfile userAgent="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.131 Safari/537.36" version="8.9.5" editor="www.draw.io"><diagram id="cfd6b513-e040-9cc8-9c77-33132335d14b" name="Page-1">3ZXBjpswEIafhuNGYKcSPSbppj10pUo59Bg5eABrjY3MsJA+fceACTRdbSutemgOsefzmLH/35iIH6r+sxN1+WQl6IjFso/4p4ixjx9i+vfgOgLOJlA4JUeU3MBJ/YAJhrRWSWhWiWitRlWvYWaNgQxXTDhnu3VabvW6ai0KuAOnTOh7+l1JLEeahm15/gVUUYbKSTyNXET2XDjbmqlexHg+/MbhSoRnTflNKaTtFog/RvzgrMWxV/UH0F7aINs47/jK6LxuBwb/ZAIbJ7wI3UJY8bAuvAYtaIm176pqEG1fYqUpTKj7Ag4VqbbTqjDE0NYL+lVcQH+zjUJl</diagram></mxfile>`

I would like to extract the name attribute and my output should be 'Page-1'

Comment: Did you try researching?

Comment: yes i did. There are no proper answers. it can be loaded from a url which is an xml file. but having the xml in a string format is not doing what it has to do

Comment: @SrinivasanRamesh Did you end up finding a solution to your problem?

Comment: yes @nickZoum.. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way would be to render the `xml` as `html`.

```js
var test = document.createElement("div");

test.innerHTML = `<mxfile userAgent="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.131 Safari/537.36" version="8.9.5" editor="www.draw.io"><diagram id="cfd6b513-e040-9cc8-9c77-33132335d14b" name="Page-1">3ZXBjpswEIafhuNGYKcSPSbppj10pUo59Bg5eABrjY3MsJA+fceACTRdbSutemgOsefzmLH/35iIH6r+sxN1+WQl6IjFso/4p4ixjx9i+vfgOgLOJlA4JUeU3MBJ/YAJhrRWSWhWiWitRlWvYWaNgQxXTDhnu3VabvW6ai0KuAOnTOh7+l1JLEeahm15/gVUUYbKSTyNXET2XDjbmqlexHg+/MbhSoRnTflNKaTtFog/RvzgrMWxV/UH0F7aINs47/jK6LxuBwb/ZAIbJ7wI3UJY8bAuvAYtaIm176pqEG1fYqUpTKj7Ag4VqbbTqjDE0NYL+lVcQH+zjUJl</diagram></mxfile>`;

console.log(test.querySelector("mxfile>diagram").getAttribute("name"));
```

You could also use `DOMParser`

```js
var text = `<mxfile userAgent="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.131 Safari/537.36" version="8.9.5" editor="www.draw.io"><diagram id="cfd6b513-e040-9cc8-9c77-33132335d14b" name="Page-1">3ZXBjpswEIafhuNGYKcSPSbppj10pUo59Bg5eABrjY3MsJA+fceACTRdbSutemgOsefzmLH/35iIH6r+sxN1+WQl6IjFso/4p4ixjx9i+vfgOgLOJlA4JUeU3MBJ/YAJhrRWSWhWiWitRlWvYWaNgQxXTDhnu3VabvW6ai0KuAOnTOh7+l1JLEeahm15/gVUUYbKSTyNXET2XDjbmqlexHg+/MbhSoRnTflNKaTtFog/RvzgrMWxV/UH0F7aINs47/jK6LxuBwb/ZAIbJ7wI3UJY8bAuvAYtaIm176pqEG1fYqUpTKj7Ag4VqbbTqjDE0NYL+lVcQH+zjUJl</diagram></mxfile>`;

var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(text, "text/xml");
console.log(doc.querySelector("mxfile>diagram").getAttribute("name"));
```

You could try using `Regex`, though if you want a foolproof implementation you will have to write a very big expression. This is a small that should work if there is only 1 `name` attribute in the `xml` and there are no `\"` in the value of the attribute.

```js
var text = `<mxfile userAgent="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.131 Safari/537.36" version="8.9.5" editor="www.draw.io"><diagram id="cfd6b513-e040-9cc8-9c77-33132335d14b" name="Page-1">3ZXBjpswEIafhuNGYKcSPSbppj10pUo59Bg5eABrjY3MsJA+fceACTRdbSutemgOsefzmLH/35iIH6r+sxN1+WQl6IjFso/4p4ixjx9i+vfgOgLOJlA4JUeU3MBJ/YAJhrRWSWhWiWitRlWvYWaNgQxXTDhnu3VabvW6ai0KuAOnTOh7+l1JLEeahm15/gVUUYbKSTyNXET2XDjbmqlexHg+/MbhSoRnTflNKaTtFog/RvzgrMWxV/UH0F7aINs47/jK6LxuBwb/ZAIbJ7wI3UJY8bAuvAYtaIm176pqEG1fYqUpTKj7Ag4VqbbTqjDE0NYL+lVcQH+zjUJl</diagram></mxfile>`;

console.log(/name\s*=\s*["']([^"']*)/.exec(text)[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

From your xml string I can see it is a data export from [draw.io](http://draw.io). There is a tool available to convert the data from the compressed deflate format to regular xml.

The tool: https://jgraph.github.io/drawio-tools/tools/convert.html